# Guess, second-guess, and higher-order guesses

Tags: meaning

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between **guess** and **second-guess**.

From Merriam-Webster's:

> **guess** means
>   1: to form an opinion of from little or no evidence
>   2: believe, suppose
>   3: to arrive at a correct conclusion about by conjecture, chance, or intuition

and

> **second-guess** means
>   1: to criticize or question actions or decisions of (someone) often
>   after the results of those actions or decisions are known; also: to engage in such criticism of (an action or
>   decision)
>   2: to seek to
>   anticipate or predict

What's the difference between "to seek to anticipate or predict" and "to arrive at a correct conclusion about (a future event) by conjecture, chance, or intuition"? If there's not much difference, why prefix "guess" by "second-"?

Or if the prefix "second-" indicates some kind of "theory-of-mind", then would the word "third-guess" be understood as "to seek to anticipate the anticipation of a person A by another person B", and similarly for higher order guesses?

Comment: One *second* guesses because there already existed a prior guess. Often it's someone else's guess, and second-guessing takes on tones of "backseat driving", but it's both possible and common to second-guess oneself; to have misgivings or begin to feel doubts about a conclusion previously drawn. So it's not the amount of people involved: it's the  amount of guesses. One could talk of third-guessing, etc, but typically that would be employed in a jocular context; as a play on words. Just as one can have both Spanish and French as "second languages", any guess after the first is *second*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition I'm more familiar with, and the one listed first by [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/second-guess) is:

> **second-guess** [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 Anticipate or predict (someone’s [or some body's] actions or
>   thoughts) by guesswork:
>   *he had to second-guess what the environmental regulations would be in five years' time*

This restricts the guessing to what others are considering doing / going to do.

I'm not sure that M-W is correct in not adding this restriction; certainly I'd only use 'second-guess' in the way OALD defines it. The *criticism* sense is largely American.